# why there is no semicolon after automatic properties

Tags: c#-3.0

Why we donot need to specify ; after an automatic property declaration

```
public string Name{get;set;}
```

How different is this statement from any other c# statement

Comment: Because there's no semicolons after `if(x){y;}`, `class X{}` and `int f(){}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because there's never a semi-colon after a code block (code contained between `{}`'s), the only go after statements.

`get` and `set` are your statements in this case (which is why they both have the semi-colons after them)

Answer (score 1):

There is a semi colon after the two statements. Get, Set. The curly braces are not part of the statements.

Think of it like

```
public string Name
{
    get;
    set;
}
```